# Use an animation as an annotation in mapbox ios

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

Is there any way that I can use an aimation as an annotation in mapbox swift. Or atleast get the allusion and affect. What I want is for an animation to place once the user clicks on the annotation. This is the animation: [lottie animation](https://lottiefiles.com/393-expanding-marker)

The goal is that I set the beginning frame of the animation as the annotation image. Once the user selects the annotation, the animation plays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure animation if you configure anitation displaying like `MGLAnnotationView`.

You can look how to configure `MGLAnnotationView` [there](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/draggable-views/).